# How can I fix my bumper dent?

Tags: honda, accord, dent

First, I am not sure if this is a bumper or bumper cover. Second, is it possible to fix this myself or do I need to go to a body shop? Any suggestions?

Car Make/Model: Honda Accord Coupe 2000

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bumper cover. What you can't tell from the pictures is if the metal bumper or other hardware behind it is damaged also. If you get under the car you might be able to see the extent of the damage. Dpending on your skill level you can do this at home. Be aware that you will have to do some research to disable the airbag just to be safe. The parts should be available at a salvage yard,possibly in the correct color. The best option if you can be without the car is to remove the cover,assess the damage, then gather all the parts. If you just get a cover you may find you need other parts once the old one is removed.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the detailed answer. Are you aware of any temporary cosmetic cover up tricks that I can use? I was looking at bumper bra/mask but am not sure if I can use them in this case.

Comment: Since the fit would not be tight due to the distorted shape you run the risk of it tearing or blowing off in traffic.

Comment: I see. In addition, I also read that bumper masks are not supposed to be on for all year because they accumulate dirt etc. Are you aware of any other economic ways to address this? The auto body shop I went to quoted $800 to repair this (with a new bumper).

Comment: Get another estimate.Ask about aftermarket /used parts. Since the car appears driveable talk to the body shop about bringing it in during a slow time.